# bin 3d points into 3d bins in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, binning

How can I bin 3d points into 3d bins? Is there a multi dimensional version for np.digitize?
I can use np.digitize separately for each dimension, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257619/numpy-interconversion-between-multidimensional-and-linear-indexing). Is there a better solution?
Thanks!

Comment: An important difference between calling np.digitize separately for each dimension and np.histogramdd is the following property of np.digitize:
"If values in x are beyond the bounds of bins, 0 or len(bins) is returned as appropriate". 
This is not the case in np.histogramdd when specifying a sequence of arrays describing the bin edges along each dimension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with `numpy.histogramdd(sample)`, where the number of bins in each direction and the physical range can be adjusted as with a 1D histogram. More info on the reference [page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html). For more general statistics, like the mean of another variable per point in a bin, you can use the scipy `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd` function, see [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html). 
For your case with an array of three dimensional points, you would use this in the following way,

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats


#Setup some dummy data
points = np.random.randn(1000,3)
hist, binedges = np.histogramdd(points, normed=False)

#Setup a 3D figure and plot points as well as a series of slices
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.plot(points[:,0],points[:,1],points[:,2],'k.',alpha=0.3)

#Use one less than bin edges to give rough bin location
X, Y = np.meshgrid(binedges[0][:-1],binedges[1][:-1])

#Loop over range of slice locations (default histogram uses 10 bins)
for ct in [0,2,5,7,9]: 
    cs = ax1.contourf(X,Y,hist[:,:,ct], 
                      zdir='z', 
                      offset=binedges[2][ct], 
                      level=100, 
                      cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r, 
                      alpha=0.5)

ax1.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax1.set_ylim(-3, 3)
ax1.set_zlim(-3, 3)
plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

which gives a series of histogram slices of occupancy at each location,

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was searching for. Also, your demonstration is really cool!

Comment: For Python 3.9.13, the argument `level=100` is no longer supported, so perhaps the answer could be updated to reflect that?

Comment: @user185160, I think this will depend on matplotlib version instead of Python version. Which version are you using? It looks like it has been replaced by `levels` from the `matplotlib 3.6.3` documentation (I can't tests without updating, if `levels=100` works for you I'lll update the answer)